# Why is the JQuery not working in Opera and Firefox on the server, but fine locally?

Tags: jquery, firefox, opera

I am making a website where one of the pages uses a JQuery thumbnail scroller script and a lightbox script to view the thumbnail in a larger image. The site works fine in Chrome and IE9, but in Firefox 12.0 and Opera 12.01 the images do not load when viewing on the internet, but everything is perfect when I view the pages locally on my machine running IIS.

Here is the [Website](http://deucalion0.co.uk/GameCenter/reviews.php?game=gameone)

If anyone could give me any insight into why the images do not load I would be grateful as I have no idea what is going on with these browsers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your image Path from `game-images\1\1-gp-small.png` to `game-images/1/1-gp-small.png`

While your local IIS is a Windows based system you can use the backslash (`\`) but your Online Machine is a Apache WebServer which is UNIX based. Unix needs a slash (`/`) as path separator.

You should have similar development environments (for local and live) to preserve mistakes like this.

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea about Unix which I really want to start to learn, I think it would give me a better understanding of web technologies!Thanks a lot for your help I appreciate it!! Something new learned!! :)

Answer (score 1):

change your image path its like **game-images\1\1-gp2-big.png* to game-images/1/1-gp2-big.png

Answer (score 1):

it`s because of wrong slashes.

It seems IE can fix it.

Path IE:
http://deucalion0.co.uk/GameCenter/game-images/1/1-gp2-small.png

Path FF:
http://deucalion0.co.uk/GameCenter/game-images\1\1-title-small.png

Hope that helps.

Bye,

J